# Ngrok returns 405 Method Not Allowed while tunneling my localhost (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, api, ngrok, http-status-code-405, http-tunneling

Currently working on SMS API retrieving Post request report after sending sms messages. After sending the report and try to callback the report through the API Middleware. After sms messages sent, Ngrok returns 405 Method Not Allowed.

**Ngrok return**

[image]

**Callback Link Set**
[image]

**Api Middleware**

[image: Api Middleware]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route is defined as `POST` request. But your image shows `GET` request. Either change the request method as `POST` or change route definition as `Route::get`.